Different error codes (23503 vs 23502) when deleting a row in PostgreSQL using asyncpg
I'm encountering an issue when deleting a row in PostgreSQL with foreign key relationships.
Typically, this raises a ForeignKeyViolationError (23503), but when using asyncpg, I receive a NotNullViolationError (23502).
Why is this happening, and how should I handle such situations correctly?

Perhaps a foreign key is defined as ON DELETE SET NULL.

no, i set ondelete="RESTRICT"

Well, you'll have to present a reproducible test case. We cannot divine how your database is set up.
